# fsockopen does not always perform the mysql queries when page is refreshed

Tags: php, mysql, fsockopen

Server A uses fsockopen, fwrite, and fgets to collect information from remote server B. Remote server B creates mysql queries and provides this info. When server A first loads, all the information (from remote server B) appears on server A - meaning that the connection works fine.
However, sometimes when the page is refreshed (on server A) none of remote server B's info is shown. Why is this?

the code on server A is quite simple:

```
function test_http_request($path, $host, $test_request, $port=80){
    $test_request_proc= test_encode($test_request);
    //http request  
    $http_request  = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $http_request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
    $http_request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\n";
    $http_request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($test_request_proc) . "\r\n";
    $http_request .= "User-Agent: testConnection/PHP\r\n";
    $http_request .= "\r\n";
    $http_request .= $test_request_proc;
    /////output
    $test_resource = '';
    //open socket
    if(false == ($test_connect =@fsockopen('[remote server Bs IP ]', $port, $errno, $errstr, 10))){die('could not open test connection');}
    //send http_request 
    fwrite($test_connect, $http_request);
    //get response 
    while(!feof($test_connect))$test_resource .= fgets($test_connect, 1160);
    //close socket 
    fclose($test_connect);

    $test_resource = explode("\r\n\r\n", $test_resource, 2);
    return $test_resource;
}
```

According to remote server B's error logs the mysql queries (that are performed to supply the info to server A) are not being performed (the resource is boolean). Sometimes they are performed and sometimes they are not being performed. The problem is not in the query language as it works perfectly when the query is requested and performed on remote server B. Only when server A requests the info through fsockopen() does the problem crop up.
**note:** the problem lies solely in the mysql queries performed by remote server B, any text outputted before-hand appears every time.
Thanks for your time

Comment: I think you need to post some examples of srv A and B.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two sockets talking to each other like you have - with a "while(true)" - and you restart one of them, the other one is still trying to communicate with the first instance. You need to look for some indication that the (restarted) server has disconnected and reopen the connection. Essentially one side of the conversation has hung up but the other side is still listening.. to nothing.

Comment: this sounds right. I am still new at this though. How would you suggest I go about this?

Comment: Im not familiar with 'fsockopen', 'fgets', etc but I'd bet there is some signal that one side of the conversation has closed.  Also - (just peeked) - the 'fgets' function uses the second param as a length. You are blocking until you get all the values. Try a smaller value (or 1) and build the response yourself. This would let you know if the connection is closed.